# User inputs based on if statements

Tags: python

I am trying to make a quiz for a university project. And basically, I want the people to only be able to progress if they select the answer I want them to select. So I have chosen to use an "Input 1 for this answer, 2 for this answer."

If they input "1" I want it to tell them it was the wrong answer and then return them to the same question so that they have the opportunity to select "2", the right answer, and then it will go to the next question.

Please help.
Thanks.

This is where I am now.

```
question1 = None
while question1 is not "2":
    question1 = simpledialog.askinteger("Question 1", "Would you rather benefit: \n\n(1) The Environment \n(2) The Economy")
    messagebox.showinfo("Nope!", "Wrong!")
question2 = None
while question2 is not "2":
    question2 = simpledialog.askinteger("Question 2", "Would you rather do something: \n\n(1) Mediocre and become famous \n(2) Great and take no credit.")
    messagebox.showinfo("Nope!", "Wrong!")
```

Comment: So you want your users to answer the same question over and over again *while* their answer is incorrect, and only have them proceed on a correct answer. **Hint 1**: [`while`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) is a keyword in Python. [Look it up.](https://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) **Hint 2**: Have a variable to hold the answer the user gives in the `while` loop, but initialize it some something that isn't the right answer (e.g. `None`) already _before_ the loop, so that you are guaranteed to enter the loop at all.

Comment: Whew, I'm really sorry, but I don't quite know how to make that happen.

Comment: See where I am now above.

Comment: Doesn't look too bad for Question 1. Does it do what you want? You can avoid stating the first question twice in your code by replacing the first line with `question1 = None`. Because `None` is not `"2"`, the question will then be asked at least once by the `askinteger` call within the `while`-loop. For the second question, you'll probably want to repeat that `while`-loop pattern.

Comment: Oh, while many Python implementations deduplicate strings, you shouldn't count on string literals being singletons. Compare them with `!=` rather than `is not`.

Comment: I have amended the code to what it is now. All that happens is it keeps going back to question1. It doesn't accept "2" as the correct answer and let you progress to question2. Everything is just wrong.

Comment: Does `simpledialog.askinteger` return a `string` or an `int`?